# YUM Server Configuration Error on VirtualBox

Tags: ftp, virtualbox, yum

I am using two SL6.0 virtual machines on VirtualBox.  I want to create a YUM environment. YUM server has been successfully created and the YUM client has also been configured correctly.

But when I run `yum list all` or `yum install packagename* -y` on the client, the following error shows up:

```
ftp://192.168.0.101/rhel6/dvd/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 7 - ""
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: client. Please verify its path and try again
```

In my attempts to solve this problem I renamed the default files sl.repo and sl-updates.repo to sl.repo.bak and sl-updates.repo.bak, thinking maybe the stuff inside them is creating problems, but to no avail...

I can successfully ping the server.  The repo file is correctly configured.  From what I have read on the net, this is a pretty common error, and occurs for no apparent reason.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Python errors are normally a result of changing the DEFAULT and REQUIRED version of python to something else by manually replacing it.Did you do something like that?

Comment: No I didn't do that.I think the error has something to do with my ftp connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Firewall settings to ensure FTP is not blocked.

Comment: You are right the culprit is the firewall on the server side.Now it works.Thank You very much.

Comment: That's great.Please don't forget to close the question.